# Importing a CSV file in Java

Tags: java, database, csv

I'm currently working on a program that needs to read in a CSV file in Java. Now I've got the file to load properly, that's not a problem, and I want add user information into database from csv file. however it comes out as a list of value. following is my file format

```
first_name1, last_name1,(group1,group2,group3)
first_name2, last_name2,(group1,group2,group3)
```

so want to add in database as

```
firstname1,lastname1,group1
firstname1,lastname1,group2
firstname1,lastname1,group1
firstname2,lastname2,group1
...
```

so how should i split all this and and store in database?

The file has a series of records that I want to put into a database, so if anyone has any ideas about that too, then please let me know.

Any suggestions would be much obliged.

Comment: Iterate over each of the groups and insert them?  You could split the tokens using either a regex or a standard string.split, and do the iteration using a for loop.

Comment: It's pretty simple: load the file using an existing CSV reader (not the one from openbyte, it cannot handle CSV files generated by Excel), read it line by line, convert each line into multiple database records, save each record in the database, close the file, commit the database actions, close the database connection.

Comment: @Mikola, Roland lllig: could you please some example for splitting csv file. basically i want structure of DTO class. such as String firstname; string lastname, List group[]; how can i add into this and store into database?

Answer (score 1):

- Read the file (BufferedFileReader)
- Iterate over the lines (for-loop)
- Break up the lines into variables (StringTokenizer)
- Put together the query (String)
- Execute the query on your database (SQL)

  ```
  public void test(String line) {
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
      StringTokenizer t1 = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
      String firstName = (String) t1.nextElement();
      String lastName = (String) t1.nextElement();
      String temp = (String) t1.nextElement();
      temp = temp.replaceAll("(", "").replaceAll(")", "");
      List<String> usergroups = new ArrayList<String>();
      StringTokenizer t2 = new StringTokenizer(temp, ",");
      while (t2.hasMoreElements()) {
          String element = (String) t2.nextElement();
          usergroups.add(element);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: @molske: could you please some example for splitting csv file. basically i want structure of DTO class. such as String firstname; string lastname, List group[]; how can i add into this and store into database?

Comment: Quick (untested) version to get the hint of how to handle it

Comment: @molske: what is used of following line                      "List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();"

Comment: It's a list of Strings containing your groups, items get added to it in the while loop

Comment: @Molske: some changes in csv file format. following is my file format FirstName, LastName, userid, role, group1,group2,group3. i want to split this and store into firstname, lastaname,role and list of group variable. so how can split groups and store into list of group. we are using comma as separator for splitting data.

Comment: keep using t1.nextElement() for your variables and iterate over t1 (like the t2 example) for storing your groups. t2 is now obsolete ..

Answer (score 0):

There's a library called [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) that does all the heavy lifting for you. It automatically handles issues like imbedded commas in double-quoted values, etc.

The maven dependancy definition is:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I've used it and can recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for this new interesting things. could you provide more details or example on this. basically i want to assign all this user information to my userDTO class. so how can i create DTO for this and assign all this value to userDTO class and stored into database

Answer (score 0):

You should look into openCSV. They support a javabeans mapping that will let you name the columns and map that into your DTO: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#javabean-integration
One issue I see is the group nesting you're using with the parenthesis. 
If you have any control on the production of the file,  I'd replace the separator inside '(' and ')' to be something else than a comma. That way your CSV parser can ignore those in the first pass. You will have a bean like:

```
firstname: John
lastname: Doe
tempGroups: (group1;group2)
```

You can then easily split the groups using

```
String[] groups = tempGroups.split("[();]")
```

To put that in the DB, iterate over the collection of beans and for each bean, iterate over the collection of groups to add each individual user with its group.

```
for (User user:Users) {
   for  (String group:user.getGroups()) {
       db.insert(user.getFirstname(), user.getLastName(), group);
   }
}
```

Comment: @bohemian: Thanks for this new interesting things. could you provide more details or example on this. basically i want to assign all this user information to my userDTO class. so how can i create DTO for this and assign all this value to userDTO class and stored into database

Comment: how should i create  DTO class for User.In  user  consist of following details
firstname, lastname,lastname.role,group1#group#group3. so basically role consist of group1,group2,group3.